# java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider "zip" not found

Tags: java

I am trying to use the java.nio-API for traversing a .zip-file, but I get a `ProviderNotFoundException` when I try to call `FileSystems.newFileSystem`.

I have also tried changing the `zip:file:` to `jar:file:`, but I get the same kind of exception except that the message says `Provider "jar" not found`.

I have also tried using `FileSystems.newFileSystem(Path, null)` directly without creating an `URI` first.

**Output:**

```
Reading zip-file: /home/pyknic/Downloads/Walking.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider "zip" not found
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:364)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:293)
    at com.github.pyknic.zipfs.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.github.pyknic.zipfs;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import static java.lang.String.format;
import static java.util.Collections.singletonMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        final Path zipFile = Paths.get(args[0]);

        System.out.println("Reading zip-file: " + zipFile);
        final URI uri = URI.create("zip:file:" + zipFile.toUri().getPath().replace(" ", "%20"));

        try (final FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, singletonMap("create", "true"))) {
            final long entriesRead = StreamSupport.stream(fs.getRootDirectories().spliterator(), false)
                .flatMap(root -> {
                    try {
                        return Files.walk(root);
                    } catch (final IOException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(format(
                            "Error traversing zip file system '%s', root: '%s'.",
                            zipFile, root), ex);
                    }
                }).mapToLong(file -> {
                    try {
                        Files.lines(file).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
                        return 1;
                    } catch (final IOException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(format(
                            "Error modifying DAE-file '%s' in zip file system '%s'.",
                            file, zipFile), ex);
                    }
                }).sum();

            System.out.format("A total of %,d entries read.%n", entriesRead);

        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(format(
                "Error reading zip-file '%s'.", zipFile
            ), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get access to the file system of a zip-file with the Java Nio-APIs?

Comment: Did this use to work in Java 8 and now it doesn't?

Comment: I don't have the JDK 8 installed on my machine any more, but I tried compiling the code with target level 1.8 and running it from within IDEA. Same problem there. Not sure if it is JDK 9 related.

Comment: `FileSystem.newFileSystem` -- *`ProviderNotFoundException` - if a provider supporting the URI scheme is not installed* seems not pertaining to Java9

Comment: I have run it on another machine now with JDK 1.8.0_121 and I get the same exception. It does not seem to be JDK 9-related.

Comment: Right, there's nothing JDK 9 specific. The code needs be changed to `fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFile, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())` or `fs =  FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("jar:" + zipFile.toUri()), Map.of());`.

Comment: Alans solution worked worked!

Comment: Check whether you have `com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider` loaded from `zipfs.jar` extension: `for (FileSystemProvider provider: FileSystemProvider.installedProviders()) { System.out.println(provider); }`

Comment: Have you checked [Zip File System Provider documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html)?